# How to get data after click change file upload with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a problem, how to get input type text after click change upload files?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".example").click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(".test2").click();
  });

  $(".test2").change(function () {
    var titlename = $(".test1").val();
    var filename = $(this)[0].files[0].name;
    $(".button1").click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(".demo1").html("Title: "+titlename);
      $(".demo2").html("Files: "+filename);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.example {
cursor: pointer;
width: 150px;
height: 100px;
text-align: center;
margin: 10px 0;
border: 2px dashed #000
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="test1" class="test1" placeholder="title files">
<div class="example">
<h3>Click Here Uploads</h3>
<input type="file" name="test2" class="test2" hidden>
</div>
<button class="button1">Submit</button>
<div class="demo1"></div>
<div class="demo2"></div>
```

**first example:** input title then upload files and send, get (title & file)

**second example:** input file then input title and send, only get (file)

I want both way to work get data (title & file), but I have tried and it doesn't work.